# Paint stripper left on overnight….?? What process to follow up on that today?

Tags: paint, paint-removal

[image]I am stripping paint (layers) off an old cabinet.  Have done 2 applications (scraped off in between). Wiped with mineral spirits…. Now this morning there are still bubbles of more paint to be scraped, but it’s not as “wet” or easy to scrape - as it was yesterday.  I thought I had done enough yesterday and would sand today to finish and then paint…but, more paint & stripper to get off…. Ugh?

Comment: You should add a picture of the issue into your question.

Comment: "What process to follow up on that today?" Decide if the job is finished enough for you, then either strip more or start adding new paint. What else can we tell you?

Comment: Doing enough can depend on how you want to finish the cabinet.  An oil/wax or stain finish requires more work than a paint finish

Comment: Sooo… I should apply more stripper to get this off?  Then sand and paint?

Comment: This is my first time posting… trying to figure where/how to add a picture.

Comment: Add a picture by clicking [edit] and the "Image" button (mountains, sixth button along in the edit window). You can choose an image from your device, from the web or paste one in. Make sure it's not too big.

Comment: At a minimum, you'll need to scrape the bubbled goop off. After that, it's up to _you_ to decide if you've stripped enough for the new finish you're planning on applying. Since we don't know what that finish is, we can't help.

Comment: I am going to sand and paint….

Answer (score 1):

The job's not really done until there's no paint left.
The stripper is always going to slightly affect the next layer down, so long as there is one.

As the stripper evaporates off, it's going to partially bubble up the next layer, then it will eventually re-set almost solid but nowhere near flat, not in any kind of serviceable condition.
Scrape off what's still soft enough, then time for more stripper.
It once took me two weeks to get a cast-iron fireplace plus 100 years of paint back to bare metal, before I could black lead it. You just can't rush it - you also don't want to be sanding old paint, you don't know what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another application of paint stripper to soften it up again.  No big deal. Use the same kind of stripper (don't change brands).

It helps to wrap it in plastic to slow down evaporation of the solvents.